# OOP project: I have a problem with the Player class. Thereby the intervals have to be given and see if the given numbers are within the interval

Tags: python, numpy, oop, project

It's about Candy Crush, which I wanted to build.
In order to do this, I used three classes:
Board, Player and main

In the class Board I create a m*n matrix with yellow, blue and pink fruits, which should represent the field.

In the main class the board is created by the user.
The player has to enter his old/new X, Y coordinates and the fruits should move (I'm not done yet).

In the Player class, the coordinates which is entered by the player should be checked.
"Are the inputted numbers valid?".
For this I wrote the method "legal_length"

Board-Class

```
import numpy as np
from Player import *

class Board:

    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
        if x is None:
            x = int(input("Enter the width of the board: "))
        if y is None:
            y = int(input("Enter the height of the board: "))
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.board_flaeche = np.zeros((x, y), dtype=str)
        fruits_liste = ["Y", "B", "P"]

        for i in range(x):
            for j in range(y):
                self.board_flaeche[i][j] = np.random.choice(fruits_liste)

        print(self.board_flaeche)
        # do I need it??
        self.player = Player(0, 0, 0, 0)



    def move(self):

        old_x = self.player.getOldX()
        old_y = self.player.getOldY()
        new_x = self.player.getNewX()
        new_y = self.player.getNewY()

        # Update position of the player instance
        # self.player.setPosition(new_x, new_y)
```

Player-Class

```
# from numpy import np
import main
from Board import *



# from x, y to newX, newY
class Player:
    def __init__(self, old_x, old_y, new_x, new_y):
        self.old_x = old_x
        self.old_y = old_y
        self.new_x = new_x
        self.new_y = new_y

    def getOldX(self):
        return self.old_x

    def getOldY(self):
        return self.old_y

    def getNewX(self):
        return self.new_x

    def getNewY(self):
        return self.new_y


    # switching positions - not finished yet
    # def move(self):
        # Board.board_flaeche[x][y] = Board.board_flaeche[newX][newY]

    # ToDo:
    #  Task: Write a method legal_length where old_x, old_y, new_x, new_y
    #        must be checked if they are within the self.board_area[i][j] range

    def legal_length(self):
        # ToDo Problem:
        # how do I get the attributes from another class in Python without creating an instance each time
        pass

    def setPosition(self, new_x, new_y):
        pass
```

Main-Class

```
from Board import *
from Player import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = Board()

    while True:
        old_x_input = int(input("x: "))
        old_y_input = int(input("y: "))
        new_x_input = int(input("move to newX: "))
        new_y_input = int(input("move to newY: "))
        p = Player(old_x_input - 1, old_y_input - 1, new_x_input - 1, new_y_input - 1)
        print(b.board_flaeche)
        print(b.move())
```

can someone help me with the "legal_length" method

Comment: This is your actual question. The rest of your post is just noise. *how do I get the attributes from another class in Python without creating an instance each time*

Comment: `Player` should have an attribute containing the `Board` that they're playing on. When `Board` creates the player, it can do `self.player = Player(self, 0, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.